How to debug failed GUI startup of Ubuntu 24.04 on Dell Precision 5820
I did a fresh install of 24.04 on this machine's 512GB SSD.  It booted fine.  I did updates, and rebooted fine.  Then I ran through my usual new machine setup which installs lots of things. Now when I try to log in, I get "Oops an error has occurred. Logout and try again" or similar wording.  Annoyingly I had set my account to auto login, so "logout" just comes back and gets the same error.
After reading other posts about this kind of error, I tried what they suggested. Mostly fixing packages, try updates - which ran without error.  And one suggested changing the display manager to lightdm, which at least got me back a login prompt - disabled auto login I assume.
I added a new admin user and it gets the same error. Which I take as an indication this is a global problem, not something weird in my own user folder.
But looking through the dmesg and syslog I don't see what the problem is.  At first, I saw the NVIDIA driver was tainted (unsigned), I tried re-installing that - which did trigger the MOK enroll, but I got the same problem, so I removed (purged) all NVIDIA drivers so it would revert to the Nouveau driver, but the problem remains.
I can use Ctrl+Alt+F3 to get a terminal login. I'm hHoping with some guidance I can fix this install.  Otherwise I will have to wipe it and start over losing a day or so of work.
I have a working install of 22.04 on the same machine. Its an old, slow spinner drive, I want to upgrade the OS and switch to booting from the SSD.  Under 22.04 this machine freezes from time to time. I assume I installed something dodgy, so this is also an opportunity to fix that too.
dmesg (129K):
link to my google drive
Syslog:
link to my google drive
.xsession-errors:
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/rcooke/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME-Classic:GNOME
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/30x11-common_xresources: line 16: has_option: command not found
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent: line 9: has_option: command not found

My Ubuntu 22.04 session does not have an .Xauthority.  The one in my home folder for 24.04 had restricted permissions.  I'll open it up and try that.
Also those errors in the Xsession log are making me suspicious. I rsync'd my old user folder over to migrate all my preferences and settings.  I'm starting to wonder if some of the old settings are what crashed me, but I was able to login after the rsync, so maybe it's not related.

see .xsession-errors in your /home/ for starters. also check permissions of .Xauthority

Question updated - thanks for the input!

the obvious thing to do is to check line 16 of that file ;) has_option moved to /etc/X11/Xsession from /etc/X11/Xsession.d/20-x11-common-process-args so maybe copy it back to that file is a fix

grep has_option /etc/X11/Xsession  shows
has_option() {
